# Exclude specific country from google map autocomplete search

Tags: google-places-api

i am using **google.maps.places.Autocomplete** services.

```
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
 (document.getElementById('autocomplete_textarea')),
  { types: ['geocode'] });

  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress();
  });
```

but i am curious, can i exclude specific country in search box? Means i dont want to populate search result in input field for US.

Comment: No, there is no exclude filter. You can only include up to 5 countries in components restrictions.

Comment: Any one have a Answer??